# How can be sure that a TFS Collection is not in use?

Tags: tfs

I suspect that a specific collection is no more in use, but I want to do some check before moving it offline.
A query on tbl_Command gives data only for a couple of weeks and it is not enough for me.

Comment: You could use the "scream test". Take it offline and see who screams.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I have used this test more often than I care to admit.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: it's a valid test, though, in some environments, you have to wait a year. Some screams are seasonal.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: 2013.2 and I was exactly thinking using that dreaded technique.

Comment: If you take the collecting offline and do not detach it the it will continue to be serviced. So you can turn it on even after an upgrade.